# How to take an open source PHP CMS offline?

Tags: php, html, drupal, web-applications

I would like to utilize the Offline web application feature of HTML5 and take a PHP CMS such as Drupal offline. But, I am not sure where to start.

Comment: define offline; do you want to carry it with you on a usb-stick or do you want to have in in a local area network?

Comment: The body clearly states that I want to use the Offline Web application feature of HTML5.

Comment: go to http://drupal.org/documentation/customization/tutorials

Answer (score 2):

First Google hit for "drupal html5 offline": http://drupal.org/project/appcache